# GWT 2.2 RootPanel CSS error

Tags: gwt

Hey guys, I'm just starting out with GWT and am getting the following error when I run the project in Eclipse

> 19:36:16.084 [ERROR] [adaptivgwt]
>   Warning:
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel
>   descendants will be incorrectly
>   positioned, i.e. not relative to their
>   parent element, when
>   'position:static', which is the CSS
>   default, is in effect. One possible
>   fix is to call
>   'panel.getElement().getStyle().setPosition(Position.RELATIVE)'.
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel
>   is missing CSS
>   'position:{relative,absolute,fixed}'
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel.verifyPositionNotStatic(AbsolutePanel.java:279)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel.add(AbsolutePanel.java:118)
>       at com.ivstel.adaptiv.client.AdaptivGWT.loadLogin(AdaptivGWT.java:29)
>       at com.ivstel.adaptiv.client.AdaptivGWT.onModuleLoad(AdaptivGWT.java:21)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:183)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

This is what my [entry point](http://paste2.org/p/1273521) looks like:

```
public class AdaptivGWT implements EntryPoint {

private static AdaptivGWT singleton;

        public static AdaptivGWT get() {
                return singleton;
        }

        public void onModuleLoad() {
                singleton = this;
                loadLogin();
        }

        public void loadLogin() {
                RootPanel.get("login").clear();
                RootPanel.get("main").clear();

                LoginGWT login = new LoginGWT();
                RootPanel.get("login").add(login, 10, 10);
        }

        public void loadMain(User user) {
                RootPanel.get("login").clear();

                MainGWT main = new MainGWT();
                RootPanel.get("main").add(main, 10, 10);
        }
}
```

The HTML file.

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- The DOCTYPE declaration above will set the    -->
<!-- browser's rendering engine into               -->
<!-- "Standards Mode". Replacing this declaration  -->
<!-- with a "Quirks Mode" doctype may lead to some -->
<!-- differences in layout.                        -->

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="AdaptivGWT.css">

    <title>Adaptiv</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="adaptivgwt/adaptivgwt.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

    <!-- RECOMMENDED if your web app will not function without JavaScript enabled -->
    <noscript>
      <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
        Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
        in order for this application to display correctly.
      </div>
    </noscript>

    <div id="login"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess is the answer to this question is in the part not shown here: your main html file, which contains the `main` and `login` labeled html elements. So could you add the html as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the position arguments (i.e. 10, 10) with the `add` method requires the elements you want to add the GWT widgets to as child element, also be positioned elements (i.e. they must have a property: `position:`). In your case the div's (both with id main and login) have no position. Better use `add(main)` instead. If you want to position your element 10 pixels to left/top use css margin or padding (depending on your use case).

On a side note, it's not necessary to have both a 'login' and 'main' div's, you could simply use one div, or directly add it to the body, i.e. use `get()`. That way you have the full control in GWT, instead having part of the structure in the html file.

Comment: Thank you so much. Removing the position arguments fixed it.

Comment: I am adding a bunch of controls directly to a RootPanel. how do you add components the root panel with x/y arguments though? How can I specify that my Root Panel be positioned, or is that not possible?